# iOS : date problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios, nsdate

I have this code:

in `viewDidLoad`:

```
dateForView = [[NSDate alloc] init]; (dateForView is a NSDate)
```

and a IBAction:

```
- (IBAction) addDay{
    NSLog(@"dateforview1:%@", dateForView);
    dateForView = [dateForView dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [dataLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:dateForView]];
}
```

When I push a button connected to this IBAction, it's all ok the first time but it crashes the next time around. This is the result of crash in console:

```
2011-06-01 11:29:55.238 Prenotazioni[554:707] dateforview1:(
    "<UIControlTargetAction: 0x1962d0>"
)
2011-06-01 11:29:55.246 Project[554:707] -[__NSArrayI dateByAddingTimeInterval:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba680
2011-06-01 11:29:55.264 Project[554:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI dateByAddingTimeInterval:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba680'
```

Comment: One issue to consider not related to your problem.  Simply adding 86,400 seconds to a date might not be the right answer for adding one day since it does not correct for DST changes.  You probably should be using NSDateComponents http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007836-SW3

Comment: I know nsdatecomponent but after I can have problem to compare with NSDate

Comment: Did you read the link I provided?  You create an NSDateComponent representing one day and then add it to `dateForView` using `NSCalendar`.   `dateForView` remains an `NSDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad`, you are obtaining an `NSDate` for which you hold a reference (since you created it with `init`). The first time you run `addDay`, you replace this with an autoreleased `NSDate` for which you *don't* hold a reference any more. When you leave `addDay`, this reference to `dateForView` becomes invalid, and the next time you enter `addDay` and try to increment it, your app will crash. The solution is to:

1. Make `dateForView` a property with `retain` policy,
2. Use `self.dateForView = [NSDate date]` in `viewDidLoad`.
3. Use `self.dateForView = [self.dateForView dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1]` in `addDay`.

Also, don't forget to set `self.dateForView = nil` in your destructor to avoid leaking memory.

Comment: self.dateForView = nil? or [dateforView release] in dealloc, no?

Comment: Any of them will do; I usually use ``self.dateForView = nil`` when I have a property corresponding to the instance variable.

Comment: You shouldn't use properties in dealloc if you can avoid them.  Release the instance variable if there is one explicitly declared.

Answer (score 0):

May be the dateForView is released. For solving this  use the [dateForView retain]; in the ibaction.But this will increase the memory

Comment: You must also release the previous ``dateForView`` value in ``addDay`` if you decide to do this, otherwise the app will leak memory.

Answer (score 0):

I have executed your code

you have to change this line:-

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

to
NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
and at last 
[formatter release];

like:-

- (IBAction) addDay{

    NSLog(@"dateforview1:%@", dateForView);
    dateForView = [dateForView dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1];
    NSDateFormatter *formatter =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    [dataLabel setText:[formatter stringFromDate:dateForView]]; 
    [formatter release];

}
```

Comment: @blackguardian execute the code once because I am not getting any crash I more thing are you using dateForView some where else in your view controller.